# Why does reading from an exited PTY process return "Input/output error" in Rust?

Tags: linux, rust, process, io, pty

I'm attempting to read from a process that's backed by a PTY in Rust, but once all bytes have been read from the process then reading from the process returns an `Input/output error` instead of the expected EOF. Is there an obvious reason for this behaviour, and how might it be resolved so that `read` returns `Ok(0)` instead of an error, as per the contract for `read`?

Here is a minimal working example:

```rust
use std::io;
use std::io::Read;
use std::io::Write;
use std::fs::File;
use std::os::unix::io::FromRawFd;
use std::process::Command;
use std::process::Stdio;

extern crate nix;

use crate::nix::pty;
use crate::nix::pty::OpenptyResult;

fn main() {
    let OpenptyResult{master: controller_fd, slave: follower_fd} =
        pty::openpty(None, None)
            .expect("couldn't open a new PTY");

    let new_follower_stdio = || unsafe { Stdio::from_raw_fd(follower_fd) };

    let mut child =
        Command::new("ls")
            .stdin(new_follower_stdio())
            .stdout(new_follower_stdio())
            .stderr(new_follower_stdio())
            .spawn()
            .expect("couldn't spawn the new PTY process");

    {
        let mut f = unsafe { File::from_raw_fd(controller_fd) };

        let mut buf = [0; 0x100];
        loop {
            let n = f.read(&mut buf[..])
                .expect("couldn't read");

            if n == 0 {
                break;
            }

            io::stdout().write_all(&buf[..n])
                .expect("couldn't write to STDOUT");
        }
    }

    child.kill()
        .expect("couldn't kill the PTY process");

    child.wait()
        .expect("couldn't wait for the PTY process");
}
```

This gives the following output:

```
Cargo.lock  Cargo.toml  build.Dockerfile  scripts  src  target
thread 'main' panicked at 'couldn't read: Os { code: 5, kind: Uncategorized, message: "Input/output error" }', src/main.rs:35:18
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

I've also tried using `nix::unistd::dup` to duplicate the `follower_fd` for `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`, but this didn't change the observed behaviour.

For reference, I'm using Rust 1.60.0 with the following `Cargo.toml` for this MWE:

```
[package]
name = "mwe"
version = "0.0.0"

[dependencies]
nix = "=0.24.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this error is expected behaviour for PTYs on Linux, and essentially signals EOF. This information is supported by a number of non-authoritative sources, but a good summary is provided by [mosvy on the Unix StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/538198/why-blocking-read-on-a-pty-returns-when-process-on-the-other-end-dies/538271#538271):

> On Linux, a `read()` on the master side of a pseudo-tty will return `-1` and set `ERRNO` to `EIO` when all the handles to its slave side have been closed, but will either block or return `EAGAIN` before the slave has been first opened.

> I don't know if there's any standard spec or rationale for this, but it allows to (crudely) detect when the other side was closed, and simplifies the logic of programs like script which are just creating a pty and running another program inside it.

It is presumed that the `EIO` described here corresponds to the "Input/output error" returned above.